# CSS nested hover events for a menu system

Tags: html, css

Here is my CodePen: http://codepen.io/ScottBeeson/pen/rxquJ

So basically when you hover over an entity, a menu slides up.  I'm trying to create a submenu for each menu item that basically mirrors the menu functionality, but slides down from the bottom of the menu.  Here is an image of what it should look like:

[image]

And here is my current HTML:

```
<div class="entity">
  <span class="menu"><div>A</div><div>B</div><div>C</div></span>
</div>
```

I can think of a couple ways to do this with JQuery, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do with CSS.  Obviously, populating the menu will be via javascript, but I'm trying to use CSS as much as possible.  So to put it in question form: If I put a static div with a class of "submenu" inside my entity, is there any way with CSS/LESS to trigger it when I hover over a div inside the menu?

Comment: Your best bet is to do this with unordered lists.  You can create your lists and sublists that way.  Use CSS to style them accordingly.

Comment: That's an interesting idea that I may use, but it doesn't really solve the question of how to display them.

Comment: Voting to close: _"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_

Comment: Actually, it does.  You set up your CSS to show your lists horizontally, and style and place them accordingly.  That really is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Sparky I can definitely appreciate that, but I was careful to ask a fairly specific question at the end.  Simply put, how can I use CSS to make an element slide down from the bottom of the menu div?

Comment: Edited the question title, hopefully it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use LESS, so I can't help you with that.

However, I made you this code, which displays the menu on hover, and the submenu when you hover the menu items. You could set up the structure for a entity like this:

```
<div class="entity">
    <ul>
        <li>A
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>B
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And combine it with this CSS:

```
.entity {
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 260px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.entity ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /*fallback*/
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    bottom: 0px;
}
.entity li:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.entity:hover > ul { /* only display direct ul child of .entity */
    display: block;
}
.entity li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;   
}
.entity li > ul {
    background: black;
}
.entity li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -100%;
}
```

I hope you can add the smooth effects yourself. Good luck.

Ow, and a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yz5VD/)

[EDIT]
Made a (bit sloppy though) animation using transitions, check the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yz5VD/1/).

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind.  I think I can easily convert this to LESS and add the animations. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :). Also added some animation to it: http://jsfiddle.net/yz5VD/1/ Its a bit sloppy, but you'll figure it out!